# Enabling Windows Server 2008 Crash Dump for IIS ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, crash-dumps, memory-dump

I have an ASP.Net application that is occasionally crashing and causing the Worker Process to reload. The system is running on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit SP1.

I get an Application Error event in the Application Eventlog followed by an Windows Error Reporting Eventlog.

The Windows Error Reporting Event log points me to a directory:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_624e5315e1074e44338812efe102157b47f6ca8_053f0ff3

Browsing the web indicates that I should be able to find a memory dump in this directory, however, all I have in there is a single file "Report.wer".

My thoughts are that I need to modify some registry settings in order to get a crash dump when this happens again, although I can't seem to find what settings I need to change.

The current registry settings are as follows

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"ErrorPort"="\\WindowsErrorReportingServicePort"
"MaxQueueSizePercentage"=dword:00000001
"PurgeThreshholdValueInKB"=dword:0000000a
"ServiceTimeout"=dword:0000ea60
"MachineID"="EAF7F17C-3D38-42B1-9C22-8CDD82DD7F90"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Hangs]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\HeapControlledList]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\HeapControlledList\dwm.exe]
"EnableHeapThrottle"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\RuntimeExceptionHelperModules]
"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\mscordacwks.dll"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\WMR]
"Disable"=dword:00000001
```

Can someone let me know what settings I may need to change/add in order to get a memory dump the next time the worker process crashes.

Comment: Not sure how you are getting this dump, but why dont you try [IIS Diagnostic Toolkit](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=iis%20diagnostics%20toolkit%20&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fen%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D15650&ei=z1PnTrOzL8nt0gHDvO2ZCg&usg=AFQjCNGsY8Xvxxt7gaeg30GnYaU6mBpGyw), Its so easy to work with and I bet you can find out whats happening in your IIS in no time =]

Comment: @thiagoleite The issue is that I am NOT getting the dump. If I have the memory dump then I can use the debug toolkit to inspect it for the errors that occurred.

Comment: Did you setup rules on it? Then your IIS crashes, under the tab Advanced Analysis, nothing shows on the list Available Analysis Script?

Comment: @thiagoleite I have now setup rules. However, it causes an unknown error when I start these rules. However, they still say Active. They are showing up as 32 bit though yet I definitely installed the 64 bit version. The system requirements also state its for Windows Server 2003 and I am using 2008 R2. If it crashes though I will see if I get a dump. Although I don't seem to be able to take one manually either.

Answer (score 6):

I have found the following articles which show how to enable the memory dump on Server 2008 R2 SP1.

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH74145

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx

I have now done this and am waiting for another crash and then will be able to confirm if these create the dump files or not.